# I want select some text to output in xml

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
```

If I want text "Bob" to be displayed, how do I fix XSLT file? I don't want full text "Bob Dylan".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Following Code:-

> <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(artist, ' ')" />

Answer (score 0):

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
          </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>**
```

This is XLST file.